# Need help to display data from external API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I fetched some data from an API, I'm trying to display the data but I'm doing something wrong. Can someone help? I have attached a photos of the fetched data on the console and my code

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'


import './Track.css';

export default function Track() {

   const [carbon] =  useState([])

   useEffect( () => {

    const headers = {
        'Accept':'application/json'
       
      };
       
      fetch('https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/intensity',
      {
        method: 'GET',
       
        headers: headers
      })
      .then(function(res) {
          return res.json();
      }).then(function(body) {
          console.log(body);
      });
    })

    return (
        <div>
           
             <p>Track</p>
             <div>
              <p>{carbon.forecast}</p>
             
             </div>

        </div>
    )
}
```

[image: data api]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you expect to happen here, but you need learn how [asynchronous code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous) and [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) work, as well as using [state with hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'


import './Track.css';

export default function Track() {

    const [carbon, setCarbon] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {

        const headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/json'

        };

        fetch('https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/intensity',
            {
                method: 'GET',

                headers: headers
            })
            .then(function (res) {
                setCarbon(res.data)
            }).then(function (body) {
                console.log(body);
            });
    })

    return (
        <div>

            <div>
                {carbon.map((obj, i) => (
                    <li key={i}>
                        <ul>{obj.from}</ul>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I recommend to you study https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

you forgot some little thing:
first you forgot the setCarbon in the useStae hook you will need it to pass the response from the fetch.
You forgot to set the state in the fecth.
You will need to add a condition to render only when the state (carbon) is set.
you need to add an empty dependency to useEffect

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Track() {
  const [carbon, setCarbon] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const headers = {
      Accept: "application/json"
    };

    fetch("https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/intensity", {
      method: "GET",

      headers: headers
    })
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((body) => {
        console.log(body.data);
        setCarbon(body.data);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Track</p>
      {carbon.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          {carbon.map((c, i) => (
            <p key={i}>
              <div>from: {c.from} </div>
              <div>to: {c.to}</div>
              <div>forecast: {c.intensity.forecast}</div>
              <div>actual: {c.intensity.actual}</div>
              <div>index: {c.intensity.index}</div>
            </p>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit mutable-silence-31p3t]

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,
Remember, state is like a place to store data for your component.
When you use fetch, you are getting data and now you need to save it to your state.
If you use state inside of your JSX, you can get the information to display.
Check out the console log, to look at the data structure that is returned from the fetch. This is what is set to the state "data". It can be called whatever you want. You can iterate through it, and dynamically display the data in JSX if you wanted, but I just hardcoded it for you so it's easier to understand.

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.carbonintensity.org.uk/intensity", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data))
      .catch((e) => console.error(e));
  }, []);

  console.log("data:", data);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Track</p>
      <div>
        <p>From: {data.data["0"].from}</p>
        <p>To: {data.data["0"].to}</p>
        <div>Intensity:</div>
        <p>forecast: {data.data["0"].intensity.forecast}</p>
        <p>forecast: {data.data["0"].intensity.actual}</p>
        <p>forecast: {data.data["0"].intensity.index}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```